# Centering ImageView inside TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem with centering image inside TableLayout (TableRow). ImageView is always on left side and I need center him.

Here is XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff2d8">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
            />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <TableRow
          .
          .
```

There is layout image: [screenshot](http://d.pr/i/uQAB)

How can I do this ? Thanks a lot for help.

Regards, Petr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your layout like this

```
 <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `android:gravity="center"` to your TableRow's XML definition.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Tells exactly what you need and not a bunch of irrelevant stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try   `android:layout_span="2"` inside `ImageView`

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_span="2"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```